# zlib uncompress a .zip file

Tags: c++, zlib

So I have an array of bytes that I would like to decompress using the `uncompress`  function in `zlib` but it always returns `Z_DATA_ERROR`. So my question is, does zlib support .zip files?

code:

```
const unsigned char zip [] = { /*some bytes*/};
unsigned char* decompressed = new unsigned char[decompressedSize];
unsigned char* compressed = new unsigned char[zipSize];
int result = uncompress(decompressed, &decompressedSize, zip, zipSize);
```

Comment: Zlib implements the [LZW compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel–Ziv–Welch) method, but it doesn't handle zip files. Zip is a file format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From faq

Can zlib handle .zip archives?

Not by itself, no. See the directory contrib/minizip in the zlib distribution.

see: http://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq11